# How do I remove entries from $PATH? I tried using nano to open $HOME/.bashrc but it doesn't seem to have what I'm looking for

Tags: bash, path, alias

I am trying to get rid of my alias for mongod and mongo because I first installed it manually and placed into the Desktop folder (OSX).

I used

```
alias mongod=~/Desktop/mongodb/bin/mongo
```

So now when I    `echo $PATH` , it returns

```
/Users/myUserName/Desktop/mongodb/bin
```

But I reattempted the installation using homebrew because I didn't want the mongodb on my desktop.
However now I need to get rid of that wrong alias on my $PATH, but I don't know how to get rid of the mongodb entry I created on $PATH.
`unalias` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Okay I restarted the bash and the unalias seems to have worked, as when I type $PATH, it doesn't show the problematic mongodb line anymore..

However, I have this problem now

Comment: When I try to start Mongodb, I get the following

Comment: `2015-01-23T21:33:40.220-0800 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10309 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating`

Comment: Try `ps -eaf|grep mongo`. If you see a mongodb process then you will need to kill it because it is your older mongo. Then start the one installed by homebrew.

Comment: 503  4548  1289   0 10:00PM ttys000    0:00.00 grep mongo
is what I got. How do I kill the mmongo?

Comment: If that is all you get then it is grep process. How are you starting mongo. I doubt you are not using sudo. Try prepending sudo to your command which you are using to start mongo. To kill a process you have to use `kill -9 pid` where `pid` is the first column in the output you have pasted. Although a nicer way is `kill -15 pid` but many times it does not work for various reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the alias. Restart your shell it should work.

Comment: How do I delete the alias?

Comment: It should be in your .bashrc.

Comment: Have you set PATH also in your .bashrc. If yes then you need to edit that also.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I restarted the shell and it's gone now.

Comment: Can you please take a look at the comment above? I still can't seem to get rid of the mongod problems.